# HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error in j2me

Tags: eclipse, ssl, java-me, proxy, http-1.1

I get the following error while trying to connect to a network in J2ME project

```
Exception java.io.IOException: Error initializing HTTP tunnel connection: 

HTTP/1.1 502 Proxy Error ( The specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is
 not allowed. ISA Server is not configured to allow SSL requests from this port.
 Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests.  )
```

Should I make some changes in settings or preferences?
I am using eclipse

Comment: can you post your code? and connect to network means? can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Most HTTP proxy servers (including ISA Server apparently) limit the ports for which they allow the usage of HTTP `CONNECT`, which is the HTTP verb that allows for the proxy connection to be made to an HTTP server. The only port generally allowed by is 443 (default for `https`).

I presume you're using a different one explicitly in your URL. You would need to move your server to port 443 or change the configuration of your proxy server to allow that port to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Proxy with Java ME as following way, here is [link](http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/advanced_info.html).

```
HTTPConnection.setProxyServer("my.proxy.dom", 8008);
HTTPConnection.dontProxyFor("localhost");
HTTPConnection.dontProxyFor(".mycompany.com");
AuthorizationInfo.addBasicAuthorization("my.proxy.dom", 8008, realm, user, passwd);
...
HTTPConnection con = new HTTPConnection(...);
```